# differences between memchr() and strchr()

Tags: c, char

What is the actual difference between `memchr()` and `strchr()`, besides the extra parameter?  When do you use one or the other one? and would there be a better outcome performance replacing `strchr()` by `memchr()` if parsing a big file (theoretically speaking)?

Answer (score 17):

`strchr` stops when it hits a null character but `memchr` does not; this is why the former does not need a length parameter but the latter does.

Comment: ... "stops when it hits a null character but `memchr` does not" --> aside from `memchr(ptr, '\0', size)`.

Answer (score 11):

Functionally there is no difference in that they both scan an array / pointer for a provided value.  The `memchr` version just takes an extra parameter because it needs to know the length of the provided pointer.  The `strchr` version can avoid this because it can use `strlen` to calculate the length of the string.

Differences can popup if you attempt to use a `char*` which stores binary data with `strchr` as it potentially won't see the full length of the string.  This is true of pretty much any `char*` with binary data and a `str*` function.  For non-binary data though they are virtually the same function.

You can actually code up `strchr` in terms of `memchr` fairly easily

```
const char* strchr(const char* pStr, char value) {
  return (const char*)memchr(pStr, value, strlen(pStr)+1);
}
```

The `+1` is necessary here because `strchr` can be used to find the null terminator in the string. This is definitely not an optimal implementation because it walks the memory twice.  But it does serve to demonstrate how close the two are in functionality.

Comment: @JaredPar: That walks the memory starting at `pStr` twice.

Comment: @Jason yes it does.  I just wanted to demonstrate the similarity between the functions by implementing one in terms of the other

Comment: @JaredPar: That's fair, I just want to point that out explicitly since I think it is often overlooked (think of the Joel on Software article about the painter guy).

Comment: Functionally there's a BIG difference in that if you're trying to compare binary data (that contains 0s), strchr will not do what you want.

Comment: @jkerian very true. But if you have binary data then it shouldn't be stored in a `char*` in the first place (or at least not considered a string).  My answer is predicated on the user having a `char*` which is actually a string and not binary data.  I'll make that clearer

Comment: Are you sure this implementation is valid? I can't find a requirement that it should, but common sense states that `strchr` should work fine on non-terminated input as long as you can be sure the character being sought will occur within the bounds of the searched array.

Answer (score 2):

`strchr` expects that the first parameter is null-terminated, and hence doesn't require a length parameter.

`memchr` works similarly but doesn't expect that the memory block is null-terminated, so you may be searching for a `\0` character successfully.

Comment: Either can search for a null character just fine. The issue is that `strchr` cannot search *past a null character*.

Answer (score 1):

No real difference, just that `strchr()` assumes it is looking through a null-terminated string (so that determines the size).

`memchr()` simply looks for the given value up to the size passed in.

Answer (score -1):

In practical terms, there's not much difference. Also, implementations are free to make one function faster than the other.

The real difference comes from context. If you're dealing with strings, then use `strchr()`. If you have a finite-size, non-terminated buffer, then use `memchr()`. If you want to search a finite-size subset of a string, then use `memchr()`.